# CodeIgniter extending library + using another library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to extend form validation library with this code:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function check_captcha($captcha)
    {
        if ($captcha == $this->session->userdata('captcha'))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }   else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', "Please copy captcha again.");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run validation I get this error:

```
Message: Undefined property: MY_Form_validation::$session
Filename: libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

I tried to load the session library at construct but I got again error. Is there any option to use session library inside or should I pass the value from session as 2nd parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter customer Controller class says session is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817366/codeigniter-customer-controller-class-says-session-is-undefined)

Comment: It is not case of this... I have autoload of all needed libraraysies and helpers in config. I am talking about Extending Libraray not about Controllers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access another loaded library from within a library, you need access to the codeigniter instance.

As you are extending the existing Form Validation library, you can access the codeigniter instance by using:

```
$this->CI
```

So, in your case, you can access the session by using:

```
$this->CI->session->userdata('captcha')
```

Answer (score 0):

libraries in codeigniter must get an instance of the CI object (what you'd think of as $this when calling session).

add the following to your contructor function:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

now when referencing properties/methods of the CI object, just use $CI instead of $this:

```
if($captcha == $CI->session->userdata('captcha'))
```

and so on. So use $CI when needing something outside of the library, otherwise, you can use $this